# SQL Insert rows into table that must have 2 distinct columns but also one non distinct column

Tags: sql, select, insert, db2, distinct

I have two tables, a `promotion table` and a `prize table`.

```
CREATE TABLE PRIZE(
     PRIZEID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
     COST DOUBLE NOT NULL,
     PRIZENAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE PROMOTION (
     PROMOTIONID    INTEGER NOT NULL,
     LEVEL  INTEGER NOT NULL,
     AMOUNT NOT NULL,
     COST   DOUBLE  NOT NULL    DEFAULT 0,
     PRIZENAME  VARCHAR(100)    NOT NULL    DEFAULT ' ',
     PRIZEID    INTEGER
)
```

The `prize table` is currently empty and I want to copy records from the `promotion table` into the `prize table`. in doing this I only want to select those records that have unique values in two columns, the `prizename` and the `cost`. I will be dropping those columns from `promotion` afterwards.

Right now I have the following sql statement

```
INSERT INTO prize(PRIZEID, COST, PRIZENAME)
SELECT r.PRIZEID, r.COST, r.PRIZENAME 
FROM PROMOTION r;
```

but this will insert all records into the `prize table`. I realize I can use the distinct keyword in the select to select unique instances of `cost` and `prizename` but in my case the `prizeid` will always be unique and since the `distinct` keyword applies to all columns in the select clause it won't help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do prizes have multiple prize IDs?

Comment: There are duplicate prizes in the promotion table. This is a preexisting table and I am trying to separate the prize information from the promotion information and then associate the two tables via a primary key-foreign key relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to just replace the `PRIZEID` value with new ones.  Because it sounds like you currently have duplicates on your `PROMOTION` table

First add all the distinct `PRIZENAME`s and `COST`s to your new `PRIZE` table:

```
INSERT INTO prize(PRIZEID, COST, PRIZENAME)
SELECT DISTINCT (SELECT MAX(PRIZEID)+1 FROM PRIZE), r.COST, r.PRIZENAME 
FROM PROMOTION r;
```

Then update your `PROMOTION`s table with the new `PRIZEID`

```
UPDATE PROMOTION R
SET R.PRIZEID = 
   (SELECT P.PRIZEID 
    FROM PRIZE 
    WHERE P.PRIZENAME=R.PRIZENAME
    AND P.COST=R.COST);
```

Then, I think from there you can safely delete the columns from your `PROMOTION`s table

Answer (score 0):

This will get the unique prizes based on prizename and cost and get the lowest prizeid for the group.

```
INSERT INTO prize(PRIZEID, COST, PRIZENAME)
SELECT MIN(r.PRIZEID), r.COST, r.PRIZENAME 
FROM PROMOTION r
GROUP BY r.COST, r.PRIZENAME
;
```